# Android DiffUtil without moving items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I am trying to update a RecyclerView based on a size (Int) passed to the adapter. I would like the adapter to add or remove items without moving any items as it appears to be now. I am sharing the code for DiffUtil below:

```
fun notifyChanges(newListSize: Int) {
        val diff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
                return true
            }
            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
                return true
            }
            override fun getOldListSize() = columnNumber * rowNumber
            override fun getNewListSize() = newListSize
        })

        // Update number of tiles and dispatch changes
        tilesNumber = newListSize
        diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
```

I then call it as:

```
mAdapter.notifyChanges(columnNumber * rowNumber)
```

Any help will be appreciated.